# How to assign a variable range of numbers and reuse it on a function?

Tags: swift

I got a function who calculate numbers, but I need to calculate numbers one by one in the range of 1 to 100, so I did a variable who have a range of 1...100 but still have the same error at the line where I call my function : Cannot convert value of type 'ClosedRange' to expected argument type 'Int'.

Here's my code :

```
var numbers = 1...100

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    buzzCalculation(i: numbers)
}
```

Comment: Add your `BuzzCalculation` method (which should start with a lowercase letter).

Comment: yeah I will, I just renamed it for the post

Comment: You never added the `buzzCalculation` method to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend creating a Playground and saving it to your desktop. I use it as a scratch pad for anything like this.

`1...100` is a range. It's of type `ClosedRange<Int>`. Which represents a range of values and not the values themselves. Read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/closedrange).

What you seem to need is an Array from 1 to 100. Do that like this `Array(1...100)`. Which means create an array from a range starting at 1 to 100.